# C++ path finding in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, path-finding

I have been struggling badly with this challenge my lecturer has provided. I have programmed the files that set up the class needed for this solution but I have no idea how to implement it, here is the class in question were I need to add the algorithm.

```
#include "Solver.h"

int* Solver::findNumPaths(const MazeCollection& mazeCollection)
{
    int *numPaths = new int[mazeCollection.NUM_MAZES];


    return numPaths;
}
```

and here is the problem description we have been provided. does anybody know how to implement this or set me on the right track, Thank you!

00C, we need your help again.

Angry with being thwarted, the diabolically evil mastermind Dr Russello Kane has unleashed a scurry of heavy-armed squirrels to attack the BCB and eliminate all the delightfully beautiful and intellectual superior computing students.

We need to respond to this threat at short notice and have plans to partially barricade the foyer of the BCB. The gun-toting squirrels will enter the BCB at square [1,1] and rush towards the exit shown at [10,10].

A square that is barricaded is impassable to the furry rodents. Importantly, the squirrel bloodlust is such that they will only ever move towards the exit – either moving one square to the right, or one square down. The squirrels will never move up or to the left, even if a barricade is blocking their approach.

Our boffins need to run a large number of tests to determine how barricade placement will impede the movement of the squirrels. In each test, a number of squares will be barricaded and you must determine the total number of different paths from the start to the exit (adhering to the squirrel movement patterns noted above).

A number of our boffins have been heard to mumble something incoherent about a recursive counting algorithm, others about the linkage between recursion and iteration, but I’m sure, OOC, you know better than to be distracted by misleading advice.

Answer (score 0):

Start w/ the obvious:

```
int count = 0;

void countPaths( x, y ) {
  if ( x==10 && y==10 ) {
    count++;
    return;
  }
  if ( can-move-right )
    countPaths( x+1, y );
  if ( can-mopve-down )
    countPaths( x, y+1 );
}
```

Start by calling `countPaths(0,0)`.

Not the most efficient by a long shot, but it'll work.  Then look for ways to optimize (for example, you end up re-computing paths from the squares close to the goal a LOT -- reducing that work could make a big difference).